# Why so few threads on a v-server?

Tags: linux, threads

I have a v-server with 2 cores and 4GB RAM. There are running different applications like SCM-manager and a few other small application on the system. 
Yesterday i tried to run one more c++ program an i get always the error that program can not create more threads. So i tried this program ([Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-number-threads-can-created-within-process-c/)) and the program tell me that i can create only two more threads. When i close the SCM-manager i am able to open 53 threads.

top -H tell me following:
`Threads:  147 total,   1 running,  146 sleeping`

But i don't understand really the limit. I thought that only the available RAM is the limit for the number of possible threads? But when i run the code from the link above on a raspberry pi i can create more than 250 threads, and the raspberry has only 1GB of RAM.

Can anyone give me a explanation for this behavior? And perhaps also a fix?

Here the content of user_beancounters:
[user_beancounters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11RXk.png)

Comment: Do you really have a server, or do you just have a cheap OpenVZ-based container?

Comment: Its not a dedicated server. Its a virtual server (strato V30), but i don't now which virtualization software there are using.

Comment: My point is that it's probably _not even_ a virtual server either... Can you check whether there is a file `/proc/user_beancounters` and if so, add its contents to the post?

Comment: I have added the content of the file to my original post.

Answer (score 4):

You do not have an actual "virtual server". You have a *container*, i.e. a small slice of a server which actually shares a single OS across all customers and only limits the files and processes that each customer can see. (This one in particular is based on OpenVZ, often used by hosting providers, but things like LXC and Docker work the same way.)

Because these systems do not virtualize the whole OS per-customer (like "virtual servers" would) but share a single running kernel between everyone, they can be much cheaper due to less resources required – but on the other hand, they can impose artificial limits on how many processes you can run, how many files you can have, and so on.

(Whereas on your Raspberry Pi system, you have the entire OS all to yourself – and it does not impose any artificial limits. That's where the difference comes from.)

In this case, OpenVZ's `/proc/user_beancounters` reports that your account is limited to **400 processes** [edit: I looked at the wrong column], and I suspect that by 'processes' it actually means 'tasks', which can be either processes or threads.

To avoid such situations in the future, stick to fully virtualized servers (usually based on KVM, occassionally Xen, Hyper-V, VMWare, and similar).

Comment: OK, I understand, I was not aware about the limits of this type of virtualization. But still is 150 threads far away from the 400 in the `/proc/user_beancounters` report. Is there something else what i misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

The machine in question is running `systemd`, and this can impose a per-thread limit to the number of threads per process.

Run the following command as root:

```
# systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax
DefaultTasksMax=135
```

This is the default config from a Strato 8 Core/32 GB VPS (Germany).

To change:

```
# mkdir mkdir /etc/systemd/systemd.conf.d
# cd /etc/systemd/systemd.conf.d
# cat << cat << EOF > system.conf
###  Override created 2023-02-18
#
[Manager]
DefaultTasksMax=1100
EOF
```

Reload these files with `systemctl daemon-reexec`.

Now check again by running the `show` command from above again:

```
# systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax
DefaultTasksMax=1100
```

There is an absolute limit to the number of threads you can create in the VPS. This can be checked in the `/proc/user_beancounters`, looking for `numproc`.

```
# egrep '(held|numproc)' /proc/user_beancounters
       uid  resource                     held              maxheld              barrier                limit              failcnt
            numproc                       274                  274                 1100                 1100                    0
```

I chose the limit 1100 in my config, because that is the total limit for this server.